# Transfer Minecraft Windows 10 ownership to a different Windows 10 account

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

I previously bought Minecraft Windows 10 using my personal Windows account on my personal laptop in the Windows Store.

Now I want to let my nephew play it on his own laptop with his own Windows account.

Can I transfer my ownership to him so he can download and play it on his own laptop without paying for it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot actually transfer the license**, but you can *"share"* it and I think there are 2 things you can do here:

1. Sign in with your account on his own laptop and download the game. Then switch to his account and then check if they can play it. If not, see #2 below.
2. Add your nephew under a [family account](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/family-settings-app/add-someone-to-family-in-the-Xbox-Family-Setting-app). Login once with your account on their laptop so you can share your library and after that they can switch to their account and play the game as a shared game with family.

Comment: I will try the first option. thanks. The link in the second option don't seem to work for me here. and we don't have Xbox; only windows 10. Will adding him as family member here work too? https://account.microsoft.com/family/home

Comment: The first approach worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I missed the comment. Yeah, https://account.microsoft.com/family/home should work for Windows 10/11 Xbox Apps as well. Glad option 1 worked which is less complicated.